# Can which be used with plural antecedents?

Tags: word-usage, adjectives, relative-pronouns

If I use *which* as a demonstrative adjective, can the noun be plural?

Example:

> Which players won the best player awards last night? *(When there are more than one who won the award)*

If the above example is not correct, what would be a better sentence?

Comment: I'd say *"Which players won the best player award last night?"* Because ultimately, the award is one though given off to many. To me, "The Best Player" is the title of one single award given to many here.

Answer (score 14):

Yes, *which* is fine with both singular and plural head nouns.

Your understanding seems correct to me: the choice of singular or plural indicates what sort of answer you're expecting.

Your sentence is fine.